# C++ - errors after changing .h file fixed only by recompilation

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a header file called `gui.h` where I keep all my gui stuff. Because of this I often change its contents. The problem is: every time I do this I get a runtime error usually related to memory. However, when I recompile all the project, everything works properly. The error occurs always after changing the .h file contents and it's always fixed by recompilation. Why is this happening? Is there any way I can fix it or I'll have to recompile entire project after every gui change?

### EDIT:

I'm using Visual Studio IDE, normal project, not CMake

### The files

- `gui.h`
- `globals.h`
- `Game.cpp`
- `gui.cpp`

### Includes

1. `gui.cpp` has `#include "gui.h"`
2. `globals.h` has `#include "gui.h"`
3. `Game.cpp` has `#include "globals.h"`

#### The story

1. I make a change in `gui.h`
2. I hit F5
3. I see `globals.h` getting recompiled
4. I see `gui.cpp` getting recompiled
5. I see "Generating code" message in Build log
6. The project runs
7. I immediately get a runtime error related to memory (access violation)

### The solution:

Recompile all the files that require `gui.h` to work manually (in this case `Game.cpp`)

### The problem:

Why isn't `Game.cpp` recompiled automatically?

Comment: The problem is probably caused by your build tool not knowing which files include your `gui.h`.  What are you using?

Comment: @churill then why is everything fixed by full recompilation?

Comment: @MarkRansom Visual Studio

Comment: @SherlockHolmes Visual studio is not a build tool.

Comment: @spectras yes it is, and it usually does a good job of auto-detecting dependencies.

Comment: No it's not. It includes one (in fact it ships with more than one). But it is not, itself, a build tool. For all we know, OP maybe made a CMake project in his visual studio.

Comment: @SherlockHolmes Neither source files nor headers influence a program after it's compiled. Maybe we are talking about different things?  When you run the program, Visual Studio should compile the changed source files and link the program. What do you mean with "when I recompile all the project"? Clean & rebuild?

Comment: The problem certainly comes from the build tool chain. To my experience, MSBuild included in Visual Studio autodetects included files from source files reliably, and should have rebuilt correctly. With a custom CMake or other system, the bug is more likely.

Comment: Just a guess: did you check file timestamps? If for some reason (for example builds on a network with unsynchronized clocks computers), the timestamp of the modified header file is *older* than the previously generated object files, incremental build will by bypassed.

Comment: @churill as a full recompilation I mean "Compile->Compile again [project-name]" option. Based on what I see after editing .h file and hitting ctrl+B the header file that includes it "globals.h" gets recompiled, but no .cpp files that include "globals.h" get recompiled. They get compiled only after full recompilation or manual compilation

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified what tool you use to build your program. What is probably happening is that the tool you're using doesn't realize that a change to that particular h file requires anyone including it (directly or indirectly) needs to be recompiled.

For instance, if you're using "make", your Makefile may have a line that looks like this:

```
foo.o: foo.cpp foo.h
```

But it really would need to be:

```
foo.o: foo.cpp foo.h gui.h
```

In other words -- foo.o requires not only the corresponding .cpp and .h file, but also this huge gui.h file.

Any .cpp that directly or indirection includes gui.h probably needs recompiling when gui.h changes. That is:

```
#include "gui.h"
```

-or-

```
#include "foo.h"
```

and foo.h has an include of gui.h.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio as IDE. In theory it should check all the dependencies, but it apparently doesn't

Comment: I edited your question and added Visual Studio as a tag.

Comment: @SherlockHolmes the IDE is not the tool that does dependency checking. The build tool is the one. Visual Studio supports and ships more than one, so "visual studio" alone does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since the content of the header file is pasted into the source files that include it by the compiler preprocessor, whenever you change the header, the program will remain the same, since it has been compiled from a source file that contained the content of the old header file.

Comment: So the solution would be to recompile the files that include the header file?

Comment: yup, recompile the files including the header and all the files containing those recompiled files ...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you could try to set `incremental compilation`.

1. Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++-Code Generation->Enable Minimal Regbuild: Yes(/Gm)
2. Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->General->Debugging Information Format: Program Database (/Zi)
3. Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Enable incremental linking: select "Yes"
4. Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->On Run, when projects are out of date: select "Prompt to generate"
5. Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->Check `Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run`
6. Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->MSBuild project build output verbosity: select "Minimal"